# In C++ syntax, can the condition of the if else, return a int and still execute the statements within

Tags: c++, if-statement

Here is the code which compiles :

```
int select_object = 0;

if( select_object )  //condition returns an int
{

     printf("Hello");

}
```

if condition returns an int and not a boolean will the hello be printed ? When I tested this it printed hello.

Any idea why even for an int it executes the print statement.

THanks

Comment: All conditions are required to be booleans. Integers have the ability to be implicitly converted to a boolean, via `value != 0`. So having an integer in the conditional is fine: it will be converted to a boolean and tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boolean logic

1 = True

0 = False

1 && 0 = False 0

1 && 1 = True 1

1 || 1 = True 1

1 || 0 = True 1

So the answer is for non-zero it is considered true, for 0 it is considered false.  If your value (your int) returns 0 it won't execute.  If it returns a value that is not 0 it will execute.

Comment: Nit:  If it returns any nonzero number, even <0, it would execute.

Comment: Well, but the interesting question is what happens when `select_object` is neither `0` nor `1`.

Comment: @sbi - as I said non-zero will execute.

Answer (score 6):

In C and C++, any nonzero integer or pointer is considered true.  So, since select_object is 0, it should not be printing Hello.

Answer (score 0):

In C or C++, a bool is just a fancy way of saying 'int with special values'.  Every logical test (if, while, for, etc) can use an int or a pointer for its test instead of a bool, and anything that isn't 0 is true.  NULLs and 0 are equal in this sense.

Comment: Technically, in C++ a boolean is a completely separate type.  The compiler silently coerces integers, pointers, etc. to be booleans where required.

Comment: In C++, `bool` is a built-in type, distinct from `int`, usually of different size, with two possible values, `true` and `false`. And, in C++, an `if` statement requires a `bool` as its condition. But there are built-in conversions from integer and pointer types etc. to `bool`.

Comment: I did say 'a fancy way of saying' simply because the complete description was unnecessary for my explanation, but yes, you guys are strictly correct.